# Show a progress bar in Youtube spfjs

Tags: javascript, youtube

With [the spf js framework from Google](https://youtube.github.io/spfjs/) i show a "loading message" (similar as gmail) on my page transition :

```
<script src=" //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/spf/2.2.0/spf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        spf.init();
        $(document).on("click", ".spf-link", function(e){
            $('.loading_message').show();
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

But what i want is a nice progress bar like the one we can see on [the documentation page](https://youtube.github.io/spfjs/) (or on Youtube or Medium), is there any good way or example code for doing that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library: https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress.
Than in your code do the following:

```
$(document).on("spfclick", function() {
  // Show progress bar
  NProgress.start();
});

$(document).on("spfrequest", function() {
  // Increment progress as request is made
  NProgress.inc();
});

$(document).on("spfprocess", function() {
  // Set progress bar width to 100%
  NProgress.done();
});

$(document).on("spfdone", function() {
  // Finish request and remove progress bar
  NProgress.remove();
});
```

Do it on ready.

Comment: I already tried nprogress, is nice but with this method the bar never go 100% width.

Comment: Try `on spfprocess` NProgress.set(1)` (in my case it goes to 100%width) and than if you want it stay for some time you can setTimeout()

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/youtube/spfjs/blob/186b6d17274f4866bebe41937247d89eda7bd355/web/assets/scripts/main.js).

**HTML**

```
<div id="progress"><dt></dt><dd></dd></div>
```

**JS**

```
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');

var position = -1;
var start = -1;
var timer = -1;

  // Animation states: start time, duration, progress complete, and css class.
var animation = {
  // Most progress waiting for response; duration is 3x expected to
  // accommodate slow networks and will be short-circuited by next step.
  REQUEST: [0, 300, '95%', 'waiting'],
  // Finish during short processing time.
  PROCESS: [100, 25, '101%', 'waiting'],
  // Fade it out slowly.
  DONE: [125, 150, '101%', 'done']
};



document.addEventListener('spfrequest', handleRequest);
document.addEventListener('spfprocess', handleProcess);
document.addEventListener('spfdone', handleDone);


function setProgress(anim) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
  var scheduled = anim[0];
  var duration = anim[1];
  var percentage = anim[2];
  var classes = anim[3];
  var wait = scheduled - elapsed;
  // Since navigation can often be faster than the animation,
  // wait for the last scheduled step of the progress bar to complete
  // before finishing.
  if (classes == 'done' && wait > 0) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      setProgress(anim);
    }, wait);
    return;
  }
  progress.className = '';
  var ps = progress.style;
  ps.transitionDuration = ps.TransitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
  ps.width = percentage;
  if (classes == 'done') {
    // If done, set the class now to start the fade-out and wait until
    // the duration is over (i.e. the fade is complete) to reset the bar
    // to the beginning.
    progress.className = classes;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      ps.width = '0%';
    }, duration);
  } else {
    // If waiting, set the class after the duration is over (i.e. the
    // bar has finished moving) to set the class and start the pulse.
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      progress.className = classes;
    }, duration);
  }
}




function handleRequest(event) {
  start = (new Date()).getTime();
  setProgress(animation.REQUEST);
}

function handleProcess(event) {
  setProgress(animation.PROCESS);
  //window.scroll(0,0);
}

function handleDone(event) {
  setProgress(animation.DONE);
  //handleScroll();
}

function clearProgress() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  progress.className = '';
  var ps = progress.style;
  ps.transitionDuration = ps.TransitionDuration = '0ms';
  ps.width = '0%';
}
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   30% { opacity: 0.6; }
   60% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0.6; }
}
@keyframes pulse {
   30% { opacity: 0.6; }
   60% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0.6; }
}

#progress {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: -6px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: alpha($purple, 0.6)
  border-radius: 1px;
  /* the following transition times are overridden by JS */
  -webkit-transition: width 150ms ease-out;
  transition: width 150ms ease-out;
}
#progress.done {
  opacity: 0;
}

#progress dd,
#progress dt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 2px;
  box-shadow: #45C2FF 1px 0 6px 1px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#progress dd {
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 20px;
  right: 0;
  clip: rect(-6px, 22px, 14px, 10px);
}
#progress dt {
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 180px;
  right: -80px;
  clip: rect(-6px, 90px, 14px, -6px);
}

#progress.waiting dd,
#progress.waiting dt {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
  animation: pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
}
```

Comment: <dt>, <dd> should be wrapped in <dl>, right? It's a definition list, just like <ul> and <ol>.